# C# SQLiteに接続しようとするとBadImageFormatExceptionが出る

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite

お世話になります。

Windowsは10,64bit、
C#(2019Community .Net4.5)で、System.Data.SQLiteを参照して、SQLiteのDBに接続使
しようととすると、BadImageFormatExceptionが発生します。

自分なりにネットで調べ、Windowsのビットの違いで出る…というところまでは突き止めたのですが、
それをどう回避すればよいのかが解りません。

実は、この例外が出たのは二度目で、違うアプリを組んでいた時にも出ていたのですが、何かを
やったらうまく動くようになったため、安心しきってそのままにしていました。

しかし、本日別のアプリを組み始めたところ、過去にあったケースと同じ状態になり、果たして
前回は自分で何をして動くようになったのか、まったくわかっていません。

System.Data.SQLite.dllを32ビットと64ビット両方入れ替えて試してみたり、構成マネージャーを
AnyCpuからX86にしてみたり等、いろいろやってみたのですが解決しません。

具体的な解決法をお教えください。

よろしくお願いいたします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: この記事 [sqliteがOPENできない。](https://teratail.com/questions/130375) と、その参照先 [【C#】AnyCPUのアプリケーションでSystem.Data.SQLiteが読み込めない](https://feeld-uni.com/entry/2015/01/17/215909), [SQLiteのDLLでSystem.Data.SQLite.dll の依存関係の 1 つが読み込めませんでしたの対処](http://hima365.cocolog-nifty.com/blog/2013/03/sqlitedllsystem.html) あたりが関連でしょうか。

Comment: 早速のご返答、いつつもありがとうございます。二番目の記事、NuGetでインストールからやってみたのですが、今度は『DllNotFoundException』、SQLite.Interop.dllがないよと怒られています。確かに、サイト様に書かれている通りにインストールしても、Interopのファイルが入ってきていません。…ただ、このようなイントールも行った覚えもなく、前回のアプリでは参照の追加は『System.Data.SQLite.dll』だけで行けていたので、サイト様に書かれている方法ではなさそうです。

Comment: その以前とは違うとしても、DllNotFoundExceptionに関してはこちらが参考になるかも。[ClickOnceでSystem.Data.SQLiteを使うアプリを発行する場合の注意点](https://qiita.com/minoru-nagasawa/items/00aa585bbfa0d217f136)

Comment: 新規プロジェクトを作ってNuGetで `Sytem.Data.SQLite.Core` をインストールしてみましたが正常に動作しています。`Sytem.Data.SQLite.dll` はもちろん、`x86\SQLite.Interop.dll` `x64\SQLite.Interop.dll` 両方とも実行ファイルのある出力フォルダーに出力されています。新規プロジェクトから試して問題の切り分けを行ってみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: SqLiteの導入方法はいろいろあるようなので、@たたぱた さんのプロジェクトでの導入方法がわかると解決の手助けになるかもしれません

Comment: ありがとうございます。だいぶ昔から組んでいたアプリは、x86の.Net4.5のdllを参照に追加して(NuGetではなく、dllのファイルを手動で参照追加)使用していました。その頃はWin7、32ビットだったので、当時は何事もなく動いていました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

回答済みマークをしていただきましたが、あまり詳しい説明ではなくて
根本的に解決していないようなので追記します。

下記の情報で
`SQLite.Native` パッケージを インストール薦めているのは 私の知識が古すぎました。
2016年以降は パッケージの更新がありません。
最新では `System.Data.SQLite.Core` を使うのが正しいです。

`sqlite3.dll` というのは .NET 以外のアプリが SQLite を使うときに利用します。
[SQLite の ダウンロードサイト](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html) から Windows 用に x86 用と x64 用
sqlite-dll-win32-x86-3310100.zip
sqlite-dll-win64-x64-3310100.zip
の中に入っていて、x86 の アプリから使う場合と x64 のアプリから使う場合で
利用する `sqlite3.dll` を正しく選ぶ必要があります。
通常は `PATH` の通った場所にある 
`sqlite3.dll` を読み込むので、間違った dll を読み込んでいないか確認してトラブルの解決を行います。

#### .net の場合は

`System.Data.SQLite.Core` パッケージの中にある
`System.Data.SQLite.dll` が `SQLite.Interop.dll` を
自動的に `x86` `x64` フォルダの中にあるものを探して
それを読み込むようになっています。

`SQLite.Interop.dll` は `sqlite3.dll` とほぼ同じ機能を持った native な DLL です。

`BadImageFormatException` 例外が発生しないように 次のような ディレクトリ構成にすることが[推奨されています。](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki)

```
<bin>\App.exe (optional, managed-only application executable assembly) 
<bin>\App.dll (optional, managed-only application library assembly) 
<bin>\System.Data.SQLite.dll (required, managed-only core assembly) 
<bin>\System.Data.SQLite.Linq.dll (optional, managed-only LINQ assembly) 
<bin>\System.Data.SQLite.EF6.dll (optional, managed-only EF6 assembly) 
<bin>\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x86 native interop assembly) 
<bin>\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll (required, x64 native interop assembly)
```

### 訂正

-- 以下の記述は ちょっと古いのです ---

SqLite で `間違ったフォーマットのプログラムを読み込もうとしました` というエラーメッセージは SqLite ランタイム本体の DLL 読み込みで x86  x64 を間違えて読み込んだ場合に発生する事が 多いと思います。

[Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) を使って DLL の読み込み状況を確認したら 間違ったDLLを想定外のDLLから読み込んでいるのが観察できると思います。

状況から判断すると `SQLite.Interop.dll` の問題ではなくて `sqlite3.dll` 本体の参照がx86,x64で間違っているのだと思います。

`SQLite.Native` [nuget パッケージ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Native/)を追加すると 実行時ランタイムを その環境に合わせて自動配置してくれます。

```
Install-Package SQLite.Native -Version 3.12.3
```

状況が改善するか試してみてください。

Comment: いつもありがとうございます。いろいろ教えていただいた方法を試した結果、何度やっても同じ例外が出るので、一度諦めてプロジェクトから新規作成してNuGetでインストールしなおし、同じソースファイルをコピペした結果、やっと動くようになりました。はっきりと解ったわけではありませんが、どうやら以前作成したアプリの中に、過去の設定か何かが残っていたのではないかと思います。本当に助かりました。今後ともよろしくお願いいたします。